# Python 3.5: Error installing Beautifulsoup library

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm trying to install Beautifulsoup library from python 3.5 following the next steps:

1. Upgrade pip: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Install setuptools `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`
3. Install Beautifulsoup `python -m pip install beautifulsoup`

My operating system is Windows 10, 64 bit. And the result that I've got is this error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JOSCAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dgi2w24s\beautifulsoup\

Screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just so you know, the section of the error you posted is not the most relevant part. The part that reads, `Syntax Error: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` is.

Comment: I'm trying to install beautifulsoup, so I don't know why I've got this error

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem. I was trying to install it using this command:

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup
```

And this is not correct. To install it correctly the comand is ...

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

[image]